# Doctrine message "Feature was deprecated" after doctrine:schema:update command

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I get this message in red box when I try to run php bin/console doctrine:schema:validate or php bin/console doctrine:schema:update -f:

"Feature was deprecated in doctrine/dbal 2.x and is not supported by installed doctrine/dbal:3.x, please see the doctrine/deprecations logs for new alternative approaches."

Symfony 5.3.12
Doctrine 2.7.1-DEV

Any ideas where and what I should search for this message? Thank you!

Comment: Does this ressource is helpfull ? https://github.com/doctrine/orm/discussions/9164

Comment: You can use verbose mode to see the exeption trace, like this. symfony console doctrine:schema:validate -vvv

Answer (score 0):

I guess these commands were deprecated because of the idea that all schema changes should go through migrations and so - be represented in code and be reviewed before execution. The old approach could not guarantee that data wouldn't be lost (as many of schema:update manipulations allowed removing column and creating a new one to rename it without migrating the values).

The better approach to update DB schema is using maker bundle and migration mechanism.

```
composer require symfony/maker-bundle --dev
composer require doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle
```

`bin/cosnole make:migration` will generate migration based on differences of schema in code (annotations, xml or yml) and a current DB schema.

`bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate` will execute migration.

As a result you will get same thing as by running `bin/console doctrine:schema:update -f`.